# How to maintain git branching while moving from test branch to deployment branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to understand the Git Branching strategy for a particular case.

As per the strategy we follow in my organization, we first create a test branch to work on any code changes. After all the testing is done and code is ready for production.

We have to create a specific branch name (as per the date of deployment).
Now this new prod branch which needs to be created should be created on top of test branch or it should be created from the master itself?
I am trying to understand the best way to handle such sitation.

Comment: Why don't you ask in your organization how you are supposed to do this?

Comment: Note the `test` branch could simply become the `release` branch if you're happy with it. You don't *need* to rename it or make a new one. Another way to think about this would be that you create the `release` branch, and then test it to confirm it before releasing it (so you may not actually need a `test` branch).

Comment: You mentioned, "I want to understand the Git Branching strategy", however, there are many different strategies you could use. Does your organization use a specific one that is already defined somewhere? Without knowing what your strategy is we can't really say the *best* way to handle your situation.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach is something I have experienced first hand.

You could have a **develop** branch (where all your code changes go to - similar to what you are referring to as a test branch).
When you are ready to release to production, you create a **release** branch - you need to create this off develop.

When your release is finished - merge the release branch back into **master**. The master branch should be seen as the golden copy of what is currently in production, but not the one to be released to production.

This way, you can continue working on the **develop** branch, while the **release** branch is being tested.
Any fixes you have to make to the next production release can then be done against the **release** branch.

Alternatively, you could just tag the develop branch and release that snapshot, if you want to avoid creating a release branch.

Alternatively you could choose to follow pure trunk based development:
https://trunkbaseddevelopment.com/

Or git flow: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow